# AC Delco production date

Tags: battery

Recently I bought AC Delco batteries for my corolla 2006 car. The sealed number is(P7967). I tried to understand it but I couldn't because most of the posted answers where for sealed with only three number, for example (P124R).

So how I should understand the date with my sealed number (P7967)? and is there any intermediate code or what? thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! From the [ACDelco Battery Warranty PDF](https://www.acdelco.com/content/dam/acdelco/na/us/en/index/parts/warranty/02-pdfs/acdelco-battery-warranty-information.pdf), your code doesn't make much sense. The "P" makes sense, but the rest doesn't. Where are you from (what part of the world did you purchase your new battery)?

Comment: I work as foreigner consultant in the middle east, Saudi Arabia to be specific. So I bought it from there.

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI...
I couldn't find any such code on my Delco battery, so i called Delco.

With no other information given or questions asked, they said to look for a round sticker about the size of a nickel on the top or sides of the battery.  Mine was on top, next to the positive pole.  It was black with white letters.  It said "E6".  They said this battery was manufactured in May 2016, so it appears the letter correlates to the month & the number to the year.   Not sure how they distinguish between say 2006 and 2016, but i know mine's not that old.

Answer (score 1):

Production codes vary with product and manufacturer. Some use month, year and manufacturing facility. Others use the Julian date, year and facility code.

P124R: 12 = December , 4 = 2014

Julian date format:
P7967:  79 = 79th day of the year (March 20 in 2017) 6 = 2016 
The last digit is the plant code. 
Julian date code goes from 01-365

The first letter probably represents the manufacturer

There are formats that have the week number as well as the day of the week and the production cycle.

P3507A for example 35 =week 07 = day A = shift which would be September 2nd 2017 -day shift. This format is used on automotive tires for example.

Comment: What if we reach the day 100? would it be as PXXXXX ?

Comment: @resident_heretic - While using a Julian date is quite plausible, it isn't what ACDelco has put out for their batteries (as seen from [ACDelco's pdf document on the subject](https://www.acdelco.com/content/dam/acdelco/na/us/en/index/parts/warranty/02-pdfs/acdelco-battery-warranty-information.pdf)).

Comment: @Paulster2- It is a lot more than plausible. I work in a business that see a variety of product code formats and Julian date is quite common . I deal with it all day.. There a variety of formats the even encode the shift as well as the time.