# car battery date codes on my AC Delco battery

Tags: battery

can anyone tell me I have a GM ac delco side post battery with a 
P041R on it as I just got this battery according to code its 04/11 is this right?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/48721/10976

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Closing this as a duplicate, but yes, if the code says P041R, I'd read it as April 2011 as well.