# Delco 79PG 840CCA has a date of P107R. What does that translate to in dates?

Tags: battery

I can not figure the date of manufacture on this battery. Please help!!! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The code of P107R = **October** (10) **2017** (7)

[This answer might help others.](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/48733/4152)